# Inserting data into a mysql database using a form

Tags: php, mysql, validation, insert

I'm trying to insert data into the 'riders' table in the 'poo12104368' database using a form. Currently I am having problems with my 'if' statements because they are not working as they should be. For example, if a user was to only type in a last name and an email address, it would let them create an account. When the user does create an account by entering their correct details into the feilds it should take them to 'newaccount.php'. Can anybody help? Thanks

Code:

```
$firstnameErr = $lastnameErr = $suemailErr = "";
$firstname = $lastname = $suemail = "";

if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){

if(empty($_POST["firstname"])||(empty($_POST["lastname"]))||(empty($_POST["suemail"]))){
echo "Something is wrong";  

if($_POST['firstname'] == null){
$firstnameErr = "First Name is required";
}else{
$firstname =($_POST["firstname"]);
}

if($_POST['lastname'] == null){
$lastnameErr = "Last Name is required";
}else{
$lastname = ($_POST["lastname"]);
}

if($_POST['suemail'] == null){
$suemailErr = "Email is required";
}else{
$suemail = ($_POST["suemail"]);
}

if($_POST['firstname'] == null){

echo "<b>Please enter a first name</b>";
}

else if($_POST['lastname'] == null){

echo "<b><p>Please enter a last name</p></b>";
}

else if($_POST['suemail'] == null){

echo "<b><p>Please enter an email</p></b>";     
}

$dblink = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "" )
or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("poo12104368");

// Query the database to see if the email that the user has entered is already in use
$rs2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM riders WHERE Email = '".$_POST['suemail']."'");

if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs2)){
$dbEmail = $row['Email'];
if($row['Email'] == $_POST['suemail']){
echo "<p><b>Email already used. Please use another</b></p>";
}
}

else{

    // Insert query to insert the data into the riders table if their data meets the required inputs 
    $sql = "
    INSERT INTO riders (FirstName, LastName, Email) VALUES('".$_POST['firstname']."','".$_POST['lastname']."','".$_POST['suemail']."')";
    mysql_query($sql);

    // The web page that the user will be taken to  
    header('Location:http://localhost/newaccount.php');  

    }   
}   
}
?>
<h2><p> Sign Up </p></h2>   

<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>

<!-- Form that the users enters their data in -->
<form name = "suform" method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

<p>First Name:<input type="text" name="firstname" style="width:20%"/>
<span class="error">*<?php echo $firstnameErr;?></span></p></br>

<p>Last Name:<input type="text" name="lastname" style="width:20%"/>
<span class="error">*<?php echo $lastnameErr;?></span></p></br>

<p>Email Address:<input type="text" name="suemail" style="width:20%"/></p>
<span class="error">*<?php echo $suemailErr;?></span></br>

<p><br><input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit"/></br></p>    


<h2>Our Links</h2>

<!-- Links to the various mediums for Bewdley Motorcycle Club -->
<p>YouTube:<a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6PVacK6L0rk-WD2wxMXMIA">BewdleyMCCOffcial</a><p>
<p>Website:<a href="http://www.bewdleymotorcycleclub.co.uk/">www.bewdleymotorcycleclub.co.uk</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

Use `flag` to handle the validation errors in the form use this `$error` as a flag.

**Code :**

```
$firstnameErr = $lastnameErr = $suemailErr = "";
$firstname = $lastname = $suemail = "";

if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){

$error = 0;

if(empty($_POST["firstname"])||(empty($_POST["lastname"]))||(empty($_POST["suemail"]))){
$msg  = "something going wrong";
$error = 1;

}


if($_POST['firstname'] == null){
$firstnameErr = "First Name is required";
$error = 1;
}else{
$firstname =($_POST["firstname"]);
}

if($_POST['lastname'] == null){
$lastnameErr = "Last Name is required";
$error = 1;
}else{
$lastname = ($_POST["lastname"]);
}

if($_POST['suemail'] == null){
$suemailErr = "Email is required";
$error = 1;
}else{
$suemail = ($_POST["suemail"]);
}

if($_POST['firstname'] == null){
$msg = "Please enter a first name";
$error = 1;
}

else if($_POST['lastname'] == null){
$msg = "Please enter a last name";
$error = 1;
}

else if($_POST['suemail'] == null){
$msg = "Please enter an email"; 
$error = 1;    
}

if($error == '0')
{

$dblink = mysql_connect("localhost", "root" , "")
or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("poo12104368");

// Query the database to see if the email that the user has entered is already in use
$rs2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM riders WHERE Email = '".$_POST['suemail']."'");

if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs2)){
$dbEmail = $row['Email'];
if($row['Email'] == $_POST['suemail']){
echo "<p><b>Email already used. Please use another</b></p>";
}
}

else{

    // Insert query to insert the data into the riders table if their data meets the required standards 
    $sql = "
    INSERT INTO riders (FirstName, LastName, Email) VALUES('".$_POST['firstname']."','".$_POST['lastname']."','".$_POST['suemail']."')";
    mysql_query($sql);

    // The web page that the user will be taken to  
    header('Location:http://localhost/newaccount.php');  

    }   
}   
else
{
  echo $msg;
}
?>
<h2><p> Sign Up </p></h2>   

<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>

<!-- Form that the users enters their data in -->
<form name = "suform" method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

<p>First Name:<input type="text" name="firstname" style="width:20%"/>
<span class="error">*<?php echo $firstnameErr;?></span></p></br>

<p>Last Name:<input type="text" name="lastname" style="width:20%"/>
<span class="error">*<?php echo $lastnameErr;?></span></p></br>

<p>Email Address:<input type="text" name="suemail" style="width:20%"/></p>
<span class="error">*<?php echo $suemailErr;?></span></br>

<p><br><input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit"/></br></p>    


<h2>Our Links</h2>

<!-- Links to the various mediums for Bewdley Motorcycle Club -->
<p>YouTube:<a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6PVacK6L0rk-WD2wxMXMIA">BewdleyMCCOffcial</a><p>
<p>Website:<a href="http://www.bewdleymotorcycleclub.co.uk/">www.bewdleymotorcycleclub.co.uk</a></p>
```

I hope it will work for you.